# Register User as Both `Subscriber` & `Participant`

Tags: wordpress

I am currently working on a wordpress website. It is both a blog and a forum.

bbPress [Documentation](https://codex.bbpress.org/getting-started/before-installing/bbpress-user-roles-and-capabilities/) says it has 5 roles:

> Keymaster – Can create, edit and delete other users’ forums, topics
> and replies. Can manage Tags, and moderate a forum with the moderation
> tools. Has access to global forum settings, tools, and importer.
>
> Moderator – Can create and edit forums. Can create, edit and delete
> other users’ topics and replies. Can manage Tags, and moderate a forum
> with the moderation tools.
>
> Participant – Can create and edit their own
> topics and replies.
>
> Spectator – Can only read topics and replies.
>
> Blocked – All capabilities are explicitly blocked.

Wordpress by default has [6 roles](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#summary-of-roles).

> Super Admin – somebody with access to the site network administration
> features and all other features. See the Create a Network article.
>
> Administrator (slug: ‘administrator’) – somebody who has access to all
> the administration features within a single site.
>
> Editor (slug: ‘editor’) – somebody who can publish and manage posts including the
> posts of other users.
>
> Author  (slug: ‘author’)  – somebody who can
> publish and manage their own posts.
>
> Contributor (slug: ‘contributor’) – somebody who can write and manage their own posts but cannot publish them.
>
> Subscriber (slug: ‘subscriber’) – somebody who can only manage their profile.

In `wp-admin/options-general.php` page it says:

> New User Default Role `Subscriber`.

In `wp-admin/options-general.php?page=bbpress` it says:

> Automatically give registered visitors the `Participant` forum role.

I am assuming that if I signup using `wp-login.php?action=register` then I am signing up as `Subscriber`

I am also assuming that if I signup using a page that use `[bbp-register]` shortcode then I am signing up as `Participant`.

This seems inconsistent to me.

Is there any way, when a user registers, he will be both a `Subscriber` and a `Participant`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hook action on `user_register` to add second role automatically:

```php
add_action('user_register', 'user_register_participant', 10, 1);

function user_register_participant($user_id)
{
    $u = get_user_by('ID', $user_id);
    $u->add_role('participant');
}
```

Put that code in the end of `functions.php` file of your theme, and this should do the trick.

**UPD:** use `wp-login.php?action=register` for registering users henceforth.

Comment: I actually do not want to use `wp-login.php?action=register`. I want to use a custom login page (page that use `[bbp-register]` shortcode). In that case what might be the solution?

Comment: "Is there any way, when a user registers, he will be both a Subscriber and a Participant." - you didn't mention that you need to do it via BBP, so it looks like you're content with both options. Anyway, this is the most stable and simple among the ones I know.